# SpringMVC REST access_token and session

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

i'm designing rest api for my application that needs user authentication.
Authentication is based on username/password and after login, server returns an access_token to be putted in http header of all future requests.

For each request, i've created a filter that check access_token params in http header:
- if present i've to check if params is the same created by the system
- if not present filter returns 401 Unauthorized.

RESTful ws is stateless, so i want to know best practice about access_token management. I'm thinking to store access_token in database but the amount of requests after login could be big so i think it is too expensive query on database for each request.

Which approach do you suggest?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my aplications I use database to store access_token as I don't see any other ways. You can also look at [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth), and for [database schema](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)